# Clausen–Scholze's Theorem 9.1 of Analytic.pdf, in view of light condensed sets, AKA is the Liquid Tensor Experiment easier now?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, condensed-mathematics

In the recent lecture series run jointly from IHÉS and Bonn, Clausen and Scholze have reworked—again—their foundations of geometry to focus attention on not arbitrary condensed sets and solid modules and so on, but the much smaller class of *light* condensed sets and so on. These are enough to faithfully capture all sequential spaces, for example, which is a very large class of spaces that contains all CW complexes, metric spaces, (fin dim) manifolds etc. Further, the category of light condensed sets is an honest Grothendieck topos, whereas the category of all condensed sets is close to being so, but has instead a generating proper class, not a set.

The proofs in the theory of solid abelian groups and solid modules became as a result much, much nicer, due to the fact that there is a very nice generic object in the category of light condensed abelian groups (free on a null-sequence) that is projective in that category—but not in the category of all condensed abelian groups.

What would be nice to know is if this new formalism sheds any similar light on the construction of the liquid tensor product(s), making the theory and the proofs easier. I've watched I think nearly all the lecture series mentioned above, but I don't recall this arising or being mentioned. What was discussed was a new completeness condition analogous to solid/liquid, called "gaseous", but I don't know if this helps with the liquid theory at all as far as simplifying what the Liquid Tensor Experiment needed to show.

Unlike the previous lecture courses on condensed mathematics, there is no running set of lecture notes, but rather Clausen and Scholze are apparently writing a book on this material. So there's no extra written material to check over.

Comment: why $-2$? ${}{}$

Comment: $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is not sequential except in stupid cases, and more generally condensed sets don't really capture spectral spaces (because T1 fails). This is one of their (few) deficiencies.

Comment: @Satan'sMinion in that case this needs editing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Examples_and_sufficient_conditions (and now I check the citation, the paper seems to be about a similarly-named but distinct concept. Whoever put this example on WP didn't read it closely enough!).

Comment: @Satan'sMinion I would not agree with judging this as a "deficiency". Spectral spaces should be conceptually captured by condensed *posets* (in fact, they are profinite posets, thus embed fully faithfully into condensed posets), not condensed sets. Compare with https://mathoverflow.net/a/441770/

Comment: @mathworker21 actually 4 downvotes now. Even one after Peter's answer.... :shrug:

Comment: I  suspect the downvotes are because the question is on HNQ and if you are not a professional mathematician this could look like casual chatting instead of proper maths (no formulas, no logical statements or theorems). More a problem of the down voters than the question.

Comment: Even further than @quarague's comment, some people might perceive of the uses of "liquid" and "gaseous" etc as obvious trolling based on some fantasy. :)  Maybe as some AI's hallucinations... :)

Comment: @Satan'sMinion sequential spaces aren't always T1 though! And apparently for a Noetherian ring the space underlying the prime spectrum with Zariski topology is sequential. What's your argument for it only being in "stupid cases"?

Comment: I am not an expert in the area, but it seems to me that the formulation of this question has room for improvement: for instance, it references external informally-published material without providing a link to it, or recalling the content of that theorem: what if those notes go offline? Or if Theorem 9.1 becomes Theorem 9.2 in the next revision of analytic.pdf? The title is long and not very informative; and it uses extra characters for clickbait rather than explaining. With a less clickbait title, I don't think this question would make HNQ at all. So these issues could explain the downvotes.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni for people who know this material, saying "Analytic.pdf" is like saying "FGA". I don't wish to make a comparison between the mathematicians, but how is a by-now static pdf of Scholze's lecture notes different from Grothendieck's typed up seminar notes?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni By the extra characters for clickbait, do you mean the "AKA is the Liquid Tensor Experiment easier now?"? I feel this part actually adds extra information to the question title, specially for people unfamiliar with Analytic.pdf but who have heard of the Liquid Tensor Experiment and are otherwise following the developments in condensed mathematics more broadly

Comment: @Emily Yes, I referred to that part. I see your point that the title makes sense for the intended audience of experts, but in the end part 2 is there just to introduce the catchy keyword; it doesn't make sense alone or relate the second to the first part. (Also, possibly this name attracts [metal fans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_Tension_Experiment) from the HNQ list.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I can only speak for myself here, but the second part actually helped me instantly understand what the question was about, and I would definitely not have groked it instantly with only the first part: I haven't been following the recent developments in condensed mathematics super closely, and so I didn't remember that Theorem 9.1 was the one with the super hard and involved proof, but mentioning the LTE instantly made me realise that was the one (so I would also argue in particular that it does relate to the first part).

Comment: I also think it's not really just a catchy keyword for its own sake; it does help contextualise the setting the question takes place in, or at least it helped for me.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Good question!

We've been trying to figure this out as we went along, but so far unsuccessfully. Some more precise points:

1. For many (but definitely not all) applications to geometry over the real numbers, the gaseous real vector spaces work just as well, and their theory is much easier to get off the ground than liquid real vector spaces. (Roughly speaking, complex- or real-analytic spaces are fine with gaseous vector spaces, smooth manifolds not so much. The reason is that tensor products of spaces of holomorphic or real-analytic functions behave correctly under the gaseous tensor product, but tensor products of spaces of $C^\infty$-functions are only correct under the liquid tensor product.) This is the route we've taken in the course.
2. We believe that there is a way to characterize (light) liquid real vector spaces in a way close to how we characterize solid or gaseous modules, in terms of certain endomorphisms of this free module $P$ on a nullsequence to become isomorphisms. However, in this case we are not able to see any simple way to compute the resulting completion functor.
3. If one was able to prove that there is a good theory of light liquid real vector spaces, the full result would follow. More precisely, Theorem 9.1 reduces rather formally to the light setting.

Summary: So far, the theory of liquid real vector spaces remains as hard as it previously was.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Even if computing the completion functor for light liquid real vector spaces is not easier, does the characterisation in 2. seem to give any conceptual clarity? I'm thinking, for instance, on the insight that the LTE gave on the proof of Thm 9.1. I guess one has to face the hard reality that the analysis that feeds into the machine will have a hard kernel somewhere that simply cannot be reduced.

Comment: I don't find the (suspected!) characterization mentioned in 2. very compelling. So I still feel unenlightened about liquid real vector spaces.